# How to specify directory for mnesia in cowboy application?

Tags: erlang, mnesia, cowboy, relx

Is there ways to specify path to schema in cowboy app? Maybe it's possible to set in my_app.app.src or any config file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The path to the mnesia directory has to be provided to erlang VM before mnesia application is started through application configuration parameters. In [Mnesia tutorial](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap2.html), this is done with the `-Application par val` VM arguments syntax.

What you call a cowboy application is probably an Erlang OTP release (built by relx as per cowboy tutorial). The solutions, quickly described in [Cowboy issue #595](https://github.com/extend/cowboy/issues/595#issuecomment-24896243), are as follows.

The choice between solutions really depends on style as well as some constraints. Any sufficiently complex release would use a configuration file, so it would be a good choice. `vm.args` seems easier to deal with. Eventually, you might need to alter the start script (for example to run several nodes from a single deployment), and include some logic to define the mnesia directory.

#### Provide relx with a configuration file (sys_config option)

To do so, add the following term to `relx.config` as [documented](https://github.com/erlware/relx/blob/master/examples/relx.config).

```
{sys_config, "./config/sys.config"}.
```

`sys.config` actually is a standard Erlang configuration file, also [documented](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/config.html). Specifying mnesia dir is done by adding a section for mnesia application. If no other configuration is required, the file would be:

```
[{mnesia, [{dir, "/path/to/dir"}]}].
```

#### Get relx to pass arguments to the vm (vm_args option)

The `vm.args` file is actually passed to the VM through [`-args_file` option](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#args_file). This is a simple text file with arguments.

You would add the following term to `relx.config` as [documented](https://github.com/erlware/relx/blob/master/examples/relx.config).

```
{vm_args, "./config/vm.args"}.
```

And put the following content in the `vm.args` file:

```
-mnesia dir foo
```

#### Write your own start script

`relx` actually creates a start script, which passes `-config sys.config` and `args_file vm.args` to the VM as required. You could modify this script or roll your own to actually pass the `-mnesia dir` argument to the VM.

Comment: The answer was edited to detail all three solutions evoked on Github.

Comment: Thanks a lot for expanded answer!

Comment: In the first approach I had got error, but it fixed by changing `[{mnesia, {dir, "/path/to/dir"}}]` to `[{mnesia, [{dir, "/path/to/dir"}]}]`

Comment: Indeed, I fixed the example accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

in case of vm.args, planit text -mnesia dir foo is invalid, please use format:
-mnesia {dir,foo}

Comment: Your suggested format does not seems to work, at least under erlang OTP 23.

The format is still `-mnesia dir foo`, more precisely:

-mnesia dir `'"/path/to/your/data"'`